# Blank Screen after booting 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I am new to Ubuntu Linux. I installed 18.10 and recently upgraded to 19.04. 
My laptop is multi OS with Ubuntu 19.04 & Windiows 7. I am facing a blank screen issue after selecting Ubuntu OS after booting. Despite of waiting for more than 30 minutes, nothing is happening. If I ran it with advance option then only I can see Disco Dingo desktop.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Bootoptions can be configured by pressing **e** @ selected Bootentry, add **nomodeset** after quiet splash and press **Strg + x**, this should help if it is a graphical Issue as it sets the Resolution to a Failsafe. For Persistence of these Changes, put them in **/etc/default/grub**.